# Validar un formulario mediante resultado de un consumo de servicio API en Angular

Tags: angular

Estoy consumiendo un servicio de backend en Angular para validar un numero de referencia. Sin embargo estoy recibiendo un error en la consola del navegador.
Soy novato en Angular y no se que pueda ser lo que esta pasando, cualquier ayuda les agradezco.

El consumo API lo realizo desde este servicio:

pagos.online.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {PagoOnlineModel} from '@app/pagos-online/pagos-online.model';

const routes = {
  base: `${env.apiUrl}/pagos_online/`,
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class PagosOnlineService {
  userData;
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.userData = {};
    this.today = new Date();
  }

  validarReferencia(numero_referencia: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.post(`${routes.base}validar_codigo_bancolombia/`, numero_referencia);
  }
}
```

Esa clase la utilizo en la siguiente función

modal-pagos-online.component.ts

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {CustomValidators} from '@app/core/validators';
import createNumberMask from 'text-mask-addons/dist/createNumberMask';
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
import { environment as env } from '@env/environment';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {PqrsService} from '@app/pqrs/pqrs.service';
import { PagosOnlineService } from '@app/pagos-online/pagos-online.service';

const numberMask = createNumberMask ({
  prefix: '$',
  thousandsSeparatorSymbol: '.',
});

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal-pagos-online',
  templateUrl: './modal-pagos-online.component.html',
})
export class ModalPagosOnlineComponent {

  // Masks
  public moneyMask = numberMask;

  @Input() activate = false;
  @Input() isLoading = false;
  @Output() onComplete: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output() onCancelSubmit: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  ValorPagoForm: FormGroup;
  cargando = false;

  productos: any = [
    {'codigo': '', 'nombre': '- Seleccione -'},
    {'codigo': '1', 'nombre': 'Recaudo 1'},
    {'codigo': '2', 'nombre': 'Recaudo 2'},
    {'codigo': '3', 'nombre': 'Recaudo 3'},
  ];

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private httpClient: HttpClient,
              private pagosOnlineService: PagosOnlineService) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  completeSubmit() {
    this.isLoading = false;
    // this.onCancelSubmit.emit();
    this.onComplete.emit();
  }

  cancelSubmit() {
    this.valor_pago.setValue('');
    this.numero_referencia.setValue('');
    this.activate = false;
    this.onCancelSubmit.emit();
  }
  referenciaValidator(control: FormControl) {
    this.pagosOnlineService.validarReferencia(this.numero_referencia.value)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.numero_referencia.errors.invalidReferencia = data['estado_validacion'];
        },
        error => {
          this.numero_referencia.errors.invalidReferencia = false;
        }
      );
  }

  private createForm() {
    this.ValorPagoForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      valor_pago: ['', [Validators.required]],
      numero_referencia: ['', [CustomValidators.number, Validators.required, this.referenciaValidator]],
      producto_pagar: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  get valor_pago() { return this.ValorPagoForm.get('valor_pago'); }
  get numero_referencia() { return this.ValorPagoForm.get('numero_referencia'); }
  get producto_pagar () { return this.ValorPagoForm.get('producto_pagar'); }

  unmaskNumber(val) {
    return val.replace(/\D+/g, '');
  }
}
```

Y esta es la sección html donde hago uso de la función

```
            <div class="control">
              <div class="col-md- 8col-sm-8 col-xs-8" align="center">
                <label class="label is-small is-required">Referencia de pago</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese el número de referencia de pago"
                       class="input is-small primaryFields" tabindex="2"
                       formControlName="numero_referencia" maxlength="20"
                       [ngClass]="{ 'is-danger': numero_referencia.invalid && (numero_referencia.dirty || numero_referencia.touched) }"
                       (blur)="referenciaValidator()">
                <div class=""></div>
              </div>
              <div class="control-errors" align="center"
                   *ngIf="numero_referencia.invalid && (numero_referencia.dirty || numero_referencia.touched)">
                <p class="help is-danger" *ngIf="numero_referencia.errors.required">
                  El número de referencia es obligatorio
                </p>
                <p class="help is-danger" *ngIf="numero_referencia.errors.number">
                  El número de referencia debe ser numérico
                </p>
                <p class="help is-danger" *ngIf="numero_referencia.errors.invalidReferencia">
                  La referencia no se encuentra registrada en el sistema
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Y este es el error me me esta generando
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan dar, si mi duda no es clara, por favor me informan. Realmente necesito solucionar esto.

Comment: puedes agregar el constructor de tu controlador?

Comment: pagosOnlineService donde lo declaraste??

Comment: Ya ajuste ambas cosas en la pregunta

Comment: Había copiado mal el nombre de la clase que declare

Comment: modal-pagos-online.component.ts En la linea 65. pagosOnlineService esta indefinido. Puedes enviar todo el código? Para ver por que dice esto

Comment: Listo, ya agregue la información de los archivos `ts`

Comment: Estoy bastante novato en esta tecnología, no logro identificar que esta fallando

Comment: No se si estes usando ese parametro control:FormControl que le pasas al metodo referenciaValidator, pero a mi me ha pasado que si yo coloco un parametro y luego ejecuto ese metodo sin pasarle ese parametro angular explota, tu lo que haces es efectivamente eso cuando le pones al input un blur ya que dentro del blur ejecutas el metodo referenciaValidator pero sin parametros cuando realmente deberias tener un parametro. se que suena tonto pero intenta pasarle por lo menos null desde el onblur si requieres ese parametro o si no lo usaras de momento quitalo a ver que pasa...

Comment: prueba quitando `: Observable<any>` y agregando this.httpClient.post(.....)`.map(res=>res.json());` en la definición de `validarReferencia`

Comment: por alguna razon `PagosOnlineService`  no se inyecta, podría se alguna comita suelta o algo así.

Comment: import { PagosOnlineService } from '@app/pagos-online/pagos-online.service';

Prueba importar PagosOnlineService manualmente 'ubicacion-service/tuservicio.ts'

Verificar que se encuentra tu servicio incluído en AppModule.

Comment: Eso mismo iba a decir @LudOsorio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problema**

El problema está en el `this` dentro de la función `Validador`, ya que se ejecuta en otro `context` (aunque la función `referenciaValidator` esté en el mismo archivo). Lo que significa que `this.pagosOnlineService` no existe dentro de la función.

En resumen, el `this` dentro de las funciones declaradas como `Validators` no es el mismo que el que está fuera de ellas.

**Solución**

Para solucionarlo puedes asignarle el contexto `this` de tu componente al de la función de esta manera:

```
numero_referencia: ['', [ CustomValidators.number, Validators.required, this.referenciaValidator.bind(this) ]],
```

Con `bind` le indicas el contexto que tendrá tu validador.

**Observación**

Dentro de tu función `referenciaValidator` puedes usar la variable `control.value` en lugar de hacer referencia a `this.numero_referencia.value` ya que es la misma

(Si el código que está dentro de la función que valida es correcto debería funcionar)

Saludos! Espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Por la información que da también creo que es problema de contexto.

Comment: Otra opción sería encapsular la llamada a ese método en una función flecha

Comment: Muchas gracias, era justo lo que necesitaba.

Answer (score 0):

¿Estás seguro de haber declarado el servicio correctamente en el módulo?
La declaración y llamada al servicio son correctos, así que sólo nos queda validar que esté correctamente dado de alta en el module que le corresponda.

Aunque estoy viendo que tienes declarado "providedIn: 'root'" por lo que no sería necesario lo que te dije arriba... ¿Podrías verificar que está pasando por el constructor?

Otra cosa... Que quizás sea una tontería pero... 
El "this" no estará haciendo referencia al input el cuál está llamando a la función ¿no?

```js
 referenciaValidator(control: FormControl) {
    this.pagosOnlineService.validarReferencia(this.numero_referencia.value)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.numero_referencia.errors.invalidReferencia = data['estado_validacion'];
        },
        error => {
          this.numero_referencia.errors.invalidReferencia = false;
        }
      );
  }
```

Espero haberte ayudado, un saludo!